# Java fix Error For String types on Text Fields?

Tags: java

I make a little GUI sum program.Program works fine on empty text fields but the problem is when user enter any strings in the text fields the error occur

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a34dsfsdf"
```

How to fix error for string types or any characters except numbers

This my Code

```
private JTextField textfield1;
private JTextField textfield3;
private JTextField textfield4;
private JButton button1;

public ChildClass(){
    super("Frame");
    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double number1,baseE,sum;
                String text1=textfield1.getText();
                String text3=textfield4.getText();

                if(text1.isEmpty() && text3.isEmpty()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Values In TextField", "Invalid TextFields", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }       
                else if(!text3.isEmpty() && !text1.isEmpty()){
                    number1=Double.parseDouble(text1);
                    baseE=Double.parseDouble(text3);

                    result =number1+basE;
                    textfield3.setText(""+result);
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: `a34dsfsdf` is not a number so it is pretty clear that you get an exception

Comment: Add a `DocumentFilter` to your text fields that are suppose to store numbers.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: The problem is your `number1=Double.parseDouble(text1)` because your text is not a number. solution is provided by @Blip . Or you need to check before if only numbers are in your string

Comment: I am not sure at which line you are getting error. But if it's for: `number1=Double.parseDouble(text1);`, or `baseE=Double.parseDouble(text3);` its quite valid right. You can't convert a `String` into `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to parse a string as a double.

These two calls:

```
number1=Double.parseDouble(text1);
baseE=Double.parseDouble(text3);
```

If you look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)):

The parseDouble can throw two exceptions:

- `NullPointerException` - if the string is null
- `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable double.

You should put those calls in a try catch block and catch the exception and prompt the user with the error saying they need to enter a valid number.

Something like this should work:

```
try{
    number1=Double.parseDouble(text1);
    baseE=Double.parseDouble(text3);


    result =number1+basE;
    textfield3.setText(""+result);

}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Valid Numbers In TextField", "Invalid TextFields", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: A `NumberFormatException` or `NullPointerException` is a runtime exception and it is not necessary to have it it `try-catch` block.

Comment: @Peter Szeto thanks i done it through exception handling

Comment: Also would it not be better if you could prompt the user to enter a proper number in the `JTextField` when he enters the number and not after he has pressed a button to calculate?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, that you catch the exception in a try catch block.

```
double number1,baseE,sum;
String text1=textfield1.getText();
String text3=textfield4.getText();

try
{
   number1=Double.parseDouble(text1);
   baseE=Double.parseDouble(text3);
   result=number1+basE;
   textfield3.setText(""+result);
}    
catch (Exception e)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter Values In TextField", "Invalid TextFields", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  return;
}
```

Then you can also avoid testing for empty text fields. Empty String throw also an exception.